# How can I set the first two paragraphs as metada description on blogger?

Tags: blogger, meta-tags

I want to configure my meta description to have the initial bit of my post. On my template I just have `<data:post.body/>` and there is nowhere where I can get only the first bit.

Is there a way to break down the `<data:post.body/>` to use in the meta description?

maybe via javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the initial bit of your post in a span called `initial`:

```
<span class="initial">Here's the first bit.</span> Here's the rest.
```

and then use that span in the meta description as `span.initial`.

I got the idea from the technique described in [this article](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?answer=42215)